# Can't redirect .php in nginx config

Tags: php, nginx

For some reason, Nginx refuses to remove the .php extension from the address bar nor does it recognize that files without extensions should be treated as .php files.

I added a .conf file to /etc/nginx/conf.d that looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com; # I put my domain name here
    root         /var/www/html;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        # http://www.tweaktalk.net/60/nginx-remove-php-file-extension-from-url
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything, though. And yes, I know I left it as example.com. I have changed that.

When I run `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (which includes it) it says it's fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs ? I tried your config on docker `amontaigu/nginx-php` image and it worked for me. The only difference was the `fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;` which should not matter.

Comment: @zstate No, I'm not even getting an error log generated at the location specific. The access log is the only thing being generated. *Also,* I can't even find a php-fpm.sock anywhere on my server...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just modifying the "default" config in sites-available, creating a symbolic link, and pasting my existing code in there. Seems to work!